# Sometimes BLE scan response doesn't include kCBAdvDataLocalName

Tags: ios, bluetooth, network-scan

I'm developing iOS application which works as BLE central.
I have a question about the scan response information.

My application is working in foreground and executing scanForPeripheralsWithService:options() in every 3 seconds repeatedly.

```
[_centralMgr scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil
                                        options:nil];
```

In almost all case, when didDiscoverPeripheral() is called, my application can get the **localName** of the peripheral with the key @"kCBAdvDataLocalName".
(The peripheral device is developed by other vendor)

Below is the NSLog output of didDiscoverPeripheral() with **localName**.

```
[MyApp] <Warning>: (-[MyBleCentralMgr centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:]) 
    [name:DeviceName], [state:0], [identifier:240FF7D3-45D5-C4EE-2E96-BED578225C56]
[MyApp] <Warning>: (-[MyBleCentralMgr centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:]) RSSI=-63, advertisementData={
        kCBAdvDataChannel = 39;
        kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
        kCBAdvDataLocalName = "DeviceName";
        kCBAdvDataManufacturerData = <[manufactorer data of peripheral device]>;
    }
```

But sometimes(in rare case), the scan response doesn't have **localName**.
(But it has another name in [peripheral.name])

Below is the NSLog out of didDiscoverPeripheral() without **localNam**e.

```
[MyApp] <Warning>: (-[MyBleCentralMgr centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:]) 
    [name:DeviceName], [state:0], [identifier:240FF7D3-45D5-C4EE-2E96-BED578225C56]
[MyApp] <Warning>: (-[MyBleCentralMgr centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:]) RSSI=-63, advertisementData={
        kCBAdvDataChannel = 39;
        kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
        kCBAdvDataManufacturerData = <[manufactorer data of peripheral device]>;
    }
```

The engineer of peripheral device says "I'm always including **localName** in scan response".

If anyone have information about my questions, please let me know.

1. Is this phenomenon possible ?(**localName** disappears from scan response)
2. What is the difference of localName advertisementdata and peripheral.name

Comment: I asked this issue on apple dev forum.

Comment: I asked this issue on apple dev forum as well and got reply from Apple Staff [link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25556). First, I thought callback info in `didDiscoverPeripheral()` sometimes doesn't have localName but it not correct. Peripherals can send those data in **separate** packets so central can receive `localName` other packet in the end. Second, `peripheral.name` is the **cached** GAP name. so if the name is changed in peripheral device, it cause a difference between `localNam`e in advertisement data and `peripheral.name`. Thank you.